# J Query Math for mobile apps

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

start by saying new to jquery and building apps.

I have text input fields in jquery mobile I would like to perform math functions with.

http://unionxtreme.com/apps/Calculator/

```
<form>
    <label>Width</label>
    <!--- store current DOM --->
    <input type="hidden" name="currentDOM" id="currentDOM">
    <input type="text" name="width" data-inline="true" id="width" maxlength="8" disabled="disabled" />
    <label>Length</label>
    <input type="text" name="length" data-inline="true" id="length" maxlength="8" disabled="disabled" />

    <a href="keypad.html" data-role="button" onclick="setFocus('width')" data-iconpos="right" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-icon="arrow-l">Width</a>
    <a href="keypad.html" data-role="button" onclick="setFocus('length')" data-iconpos="right" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slidedown" data-icon="arrow-l">Length</a>
    <label for="roof-slider">Roof Pitch:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="roof-slider" value="15" min="0" max="20" />



</form>
```

Here is my jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="button"]').live('click',function() {
        if ($("#currentDOM").val() != "")
        {
            var getCurrDom = $("#currentDOM").val();
            var existingCount = $("#typeMessage").text();
            if ($(this).val() == "Delete")
            {
              var mylength = existingCount.length;
              var actlength = mylength - 1;
              var str1 = existingCount.substring(0,actlength);
              $("#typeMessage").text(str1);
            }
            else if ($(this).val() == "Set Number")
            {
                document.getElementById(getCurrDom).value = $("#typeMessage").text();
                $('#keypad').dialog('close');
            }
            else
            {
                if (existingCount.length < document.getElementById(getCurrDom).maxLength)
                {
                    var AddCount = existingCount + $(this).val();
                    $("#typeMessage").text(AddCount);
                }
            }
        }   
    });
    $('input[type="text"]').live('click',function() {
        var getDOM = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#currentDOM").val(getDOM);
    }); 
  });



  function setFocus(DOMname)
  {
    $("#currentDOM").val(DOMname);
    $("#typeMessage").text("");     
  }
```

want to multiply width * length * roof slider I am using my own input pad. any suggestions on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague.

What's the best way to multiply width * length * roof slider?

What's the best way to implement your own keypad?

Multiplication is easy, the formula is right there.

Creating your own number pad seems like a waste of time. Were you aware that you can simply change the input type to "number" and most phones will pull up JUST the number pad?
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp